# SQL Grant Permission to SP_SEND_DBMAIL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I want to allow a domain user access send db emails.  I have granted access to the system role DatabaseMailUserRole using *exec sp_addrolemember 'DatabaseMailUserRole', 'DOMAIN\user'*.

The weird thing is that when I impersonate the **LOGIN** (EXECUTE AS LOGIN='DOMAIN\user'), then it now works.  However when I impersonate the **USER** (EXECUTE AS USER='DOMAIN\user'), then it fails with access is denied error.

What needs to be done to grant access to the USER not just the LOGIN?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. From the documentation for EXECUTE AS (in the explanation of the "USER" argument):

> Specifies the context to be impersonated is a user in the current database. *The scope of impersonation is restricted to the current database.* A context switch to a database user does not inherit the server-level permissions of that user.

(emphasis mine) Because the role is in msdb, that constitutes a permission outside of the database and thus doesn't propagate over. What are you trying to accomplish?